# What is the name of the part to which the gas cap connects?

Tags: part-identification, fuel-tank, saturn

I'm trying to find a replacement part for a 2005 Saturn ION.

There seems to be some detachable receptacle type thing to which the gas cap screws in. The gas cap itself is fine, but one of the plastic tabs that holds this receptacle in place has snapped off, and now the entire receptacle is loose and can come out of the gas tank. This exposes the entry point for gasoline into the gas tank, which I assume is fairly dangerous.

When I search for parts, all that I can seem to find is the cap itself, which I do not need. I need the part to which the cap screws in.

Does anyone know what this part might be more appropriately named?

[image: Part that comes out of the gas tank.]

In this picture, you can see the part that comes out of the gas tank filler hole. The gas cap is still screwed into it. Notice that it appears as though it is meant to lock into place on the car, but part of the locking mechanism has broken off.

[image: Gas tank orifice with part removed.]

This is the orifice where the part plugs in. I assume this is the top of the filler tube leading to the gas tank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fuel filler neck or pipe, it connects to a rubber hose (8) that connects to the tank (1). Hose clamps (9) are used to secure the hose. If it come loose from the tank then you need to tighten the clamps. If the filler neck is coming a loose from the fender area then you need to tighten or replace the fasteners there. It doesn't look like it's sold separately  based on the two pictures below.

It's item 7 in the pictures below.

[image]

Image from [www.saturnparts.net](http://www.saturnparts.net/)

Here's an image from another site.

[image]

Image from [www.gmpartsonline.net](http://www.gmpartsonline.net/)

Here is a picture of one off a 2006. I see where I think you are talking about it coming apart but I don't think you can get just that part.

[image]

Picture source [www.justparts.com](http://www.justparts.com/Auto_Parts/06-SATURN-ION-FUEL-FILLER-NECK-5993/22885298)

Comment: Is it possible to get the part that just attaches to the fender area? I only see the entire filler hose as a single assembly for sale. It's just the part that attaches to the fender area that is coming loose, and comes completely off. I will try to get some pictures tonight to make it more clear to which piece I am referring.

Comment: @crush to my knowledge it shouldn't come apart there at all. That is suppose to be one part. Now it attaches to the fender is that where you are talking about or is where you put the gas nozzle separated from the rest of the pipe?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance concerning terminology. The gas cap screws into a piece that is about 6-8 inches long. The piece in question has a little flap on it that keeps gas from spilling out of the hole. This piece plugs into a hole that is (on memory) approximately 4-5 inches in diameter. It has some small clips on the outside that seem to attach around this hole in the fender, which I assume leads to the filler tube pictured above. The clips have broken off, allowing the entire piece to be removed, exposing the hole entirely. I am at work, but will try to get some pictures sent to me to upload.

Comment: @crush Where that piece plugs in shouldn't come apart that I am aware of. I could be wrong, but I think it's all one piece. You could call the dealer and have them fax you a parts explosion similar to the one pictured above.

Comment: I added some pictures to my original question.

Comment: @crush Unfortunately that's part of the fuel filler tube and doesn't come separate. You can call the dealer to confirm, but I am pretty sure that it's all one piece from the dealer.

Comment: That's kind of what I figured. Unfortunately, there are no Saturn dealers anymore. I may just try to buy the filler tube assembly, and hope that piece comes with it.

Comment: @crush GM dealers can still get some Saturn parts

Answer (score 0):

He is correct in that it can come out if the clips break and in my case on an F150 its secure but all beat up and cracked over the years so now the seal (good cap) is interrmittant and can throw and evap code that comes and goes and triggers the engine check light. Ford also only sells tbe whole filler tube @ $318 in my case, gheez... I suggest trying a junkyard if you think you can release the clips without breaking and pull your part. I plan to do this as well or in my case I might try to build up the bevel thats damaged with either fiberglass/epoxy or a gasket sealer resistsnt to oil/gas to fix the seal problem.